# TypeScript: Implicit generic value type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, implicit, value-type

I am hoping to declare a generic function that resolves to a value type, not the full type set of the passed parameter.

```
getProp<V>(value :V) : V
{ return value; }


// This has return type <string>, but I want return type <"test">
getProp("test");

// This has correct return type, but require explicit generic parameter.
// Also, I have several generic parameters, and then I have to state them all...
getProp<"test">("test");
```

Comment: are you sure? I just checked and got -- function getProp<"test">(value: "test"): "test", no <string>.

Comment: yes this works, maby you use old compiler, what typescript version are you using?

Comment: Maybe you are storing the return value in a `let` variable ? `let x = getProp("test");` `x` will get widened to `string`, `const x` will preserver the string iteral type